# Return plain text

Tags: templating

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, all I need to do is return plain text (not JSON) in response to an action.  If I use `returnJson()` it returns the value with quotation marks around it.  I'm dealing with a closed system that expects a VERY specific format, so the added quotations cause the submission to fail.

So for added clarification:

```
$returnValue = "abc,123"
$this->returnJson($returnValue)
```

I get: `"abc,123"`

I NEED: `abc,123`

Answer (score 1):

So I realized I can just do die("abc,123") and get the result I need.  I am definitely open to better or more "correct" solutions though.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use PHP's [echo](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) method to directly output to the browser.

```
$returnValue = "abc,123";
echo $returnValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with a plain old `echo()` statement, even `returnJson()` [essentially just echoes](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/controllers/BaseController.php#L324) your data (after JSON encoding it, of course).

If it *feels* better, you can use `$this->renderText('abc,123');` – although [it'll also basically just call `echo()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/web/CController.php#L840) for you.